# How to fetch specific properties of a related entity?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app I have two entities: Deal and Address. They are connected via a many-to-many relationship. The Address entity has many properties - latitude and longitude are two of them. Is it possible to fetch all the Deal objects together with their related Address objects so that only certain properties of the Address objects are retrieved (latitude and longitude)?

Comment: You mean like when you are fetching them from CoreData?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: If you select all of the deals inside CoreData then you will get the Addresses by accessing the NSSet that would be associated with the Address Many to Many relationship. That way you can then go through the NSSet and retrieve the the latitude and longitude from the system. So with this you can just create an NSFetchResult with the necessary entity type Deal then you can execute it inside your managedobjectcontext.

Comment: I have tried doing it this way but what I want to achieve is that only latitude and longitude properties are retrieved from the store to keep memory usage low.

Comment: @darren102 There is no such thing as a `NSFetchResult`.

Comment: yes it is NSFetchRequest i mis-typed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to filter the results of your fetch. You want *all* deals and then just a subset of the attributes of the associated addresses.

It is not clear from your question how you want to use those results. Do the attributes of the Address entity still have to be associated to the respective Deal entities?

If not, you could simply fetch all Address entities and just get the properties you want. Because Core Data will help you manage memory by only fetching the attributes needed you could simply fetch the entire objects. An array of an attribute for all instances can then be easily generated as follows:

```
[allAddresses valueForKeyPath:@"attributeName"];
```

You could also directly set the fetch request's `resultType` property to `NSDictionaryResultType` and specify the properties in `propertiesToFetch`.

The other scenario is that you do not want the relationship between the deals and addresses broken. In this case, just fetch all deals (Core Data will use *faulting* to reduce the memory footprint). You can then iterate through your results and get each attribute easily.

```
for (Deal *deal in allDeals) {
   NSSet *allLongitudesInAddresses = 
             [deal.addresses valueForKeyPath:@"longitude"];
   // do something with the attributes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Mundi. The second scenario you describe is what I want to achieve. If I use the code you provided, will core data fetch all attributes of the address objects when I try to access longitude?